# Translation of “sunburst chart”

Tags: traduction, anglais, demande-de-mot

What's the translation of “[sunburst plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pie_chart&oldid=882120375#Ring_chart,_sunburst_chart,_and_multilevel_pie_chart)” in French?

Example of sunburst plot:

[image]

([Image source](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.00468v7.pdf) -> page 5, figure 3)

Comment: I updated my answer in order to provide you more details about it, as this question is not resolved so far.

Comment: @Ced Thanks! Seems like "graphique (en) rayons de soleil" and "Graphique circulaire multiniveau" are the best translations. "Graphique en roue de paon" and "Graphique en éventail" sound quite nice too. Unsure which answer to accept as they all bring some interesting information/ideas.

Answer (score 6):

I would say it's a kind of **diagramme circulaire** ou **diagramme en secteurs**. For further details see [this](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagramme_circulaire)

**EDIT I did deep search about it and found more details:**

The picture you shown above is also known as a **"graphique rayons de soleil"** it is part of the family of hierarchical graphs (graphiques hiérarchiques).

It allows you to see at a glance the number of hierarchical levels that exist and the proportion that each segment represents.

[image]

It was not easy but I found a source about it that you can consult [here](https://www.excel-exercice.com/graphique-rayons-de-soleil/) in order to read more about it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a variety of terms ;

- graphique  rayons de soleil
- graphique de type rayons de soleil
- graphique en rayons de soleil
- graphique sunburst
- graphiques en anneaux

[ngram](https://www.bing.com/search?q=graphique+sunburst&form=PRFRFR&pc=UE00&httpsmsn=1&refig=d0c1d406d6b34353ae0d2fd9339fb258&sp=-1&pq=graphique+sunburst&sc=0-18&qs=n&sk=&cvid=d0c1d406d6b34353ae0d2fd9339fb258)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the already suggested terms, you might also call this kind of graphic, especially when the unused part of the circumference is at the bottom:

- Graphique en roue de paon
- Graphique en éventail

Answer (score 1):

On peut contourner le besoin de traduire *sunburst* si on s'attarde à décrire plutôt qu'à évoquer. L'article dit « a ring chart, also known as a sunburst chart or a multilevel pie chart... » et c'est le *multilevel pie chart* qu'on a employé pour désigner un [graphique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Disk_usage_(Boabab).png) provenant de l'utilitaire *Baobab* et ainsi on peut avoir comme équivalent :

> [Graphique circulaire](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8872435) à plusieurs niveaux, à paliers multiples,
>   [multiniveau](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3160) etc.

On évitera de préférence de trop s'approcher du [*diagramme solaire*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=DIAGRAMME%20SOLAIRE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), pour éviter la confusion avec le lexique déjà employé (l'analyse est la même pour [*diagramme hiérarchique*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=DIAGRAMME%20HIERARCHIQUE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), quoique l'adjectif peut s'avérer utile pour préciser davantage la relation entre les éléments du centre et ceux qui leur succèdent dans la même pointe, quoique la couleur joue souvent déjà ce rôle). On notera de plus que la configuration des segments du graphique ne ressemble pas toujours à celle des rayons (d'un soleil ou autre) de sorte que l'analogie est au demeurant imparfaite.